# How to change the color of cmd for tomcat

Tags: windows, cmd, tomcat7

I have a windows server where I have deployed multiple instances of Tomcat6 in different port.
Its hard to distinguish which console is for which port, so I want separate tomcat to open with different background colors.

I found a command in windows to open a cmd with background color.

```
cmd /k "color 27"
```

How do I edit the startup.bat or catalina.bat in the tomcat so that the color property be applied for the console window opened for Tomcat. I am planning to edit specific tomcat startup script with specific color.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shortcut for the .bat file and then:

```
Right click on shortcut -> Properties -> Colors
```

Choose your color and it's done I think.

Comment: It's very strange, can you tell me which file is exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I did not exactly find a way to change the color of the Tomcat console, But I changed the title that appears in the top of the console.

Default: All the tomcat console's title is "Tomcat"

I changed it to Tomcat_, I could easily recognize which console is for which port.

To do this, I edited the bin/catalina.bat . Find the line

```
if "%TITLE%" == "" set TITLE=Tomcat
```

and change it to

```
if "%TITLE%" == "" set TITLE=Tomcat_2443
```

or append the port,  that instance of tomcat is configured to run. Thats it.